# in react-redux and redux-saga what's a proper method of transitioning to a new route after an async call succeeds?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, redux-saga, react-router-redux

i'm using react, redux, and redux-saga, and react-router-redux.  i'm looking for a 'right' way to transition to a new route after a successful async call.

for example, a user submits an order form and is redirected to a thanks page.  behind the scenes, we

- current route is `orders/new`
- `dispatch(submitOrder())`
- `submitOrder()` saga runs, async network call
- api returns success, `SUBMIT_ORDER_SUCCESS` action is dispatched

at this point i want to transition to `orders/:orderId/complete`.

where/how is the right way to do this?

using `OrderFormContainer.componentWillReceiveProps()` hook is possible, checking a bool like `nextProps.submitDidSucceed` and then calling a transition action - but that's brittle and feels fundamentally wrong.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076600/how-to-achieve-callbacks-in-redux-saga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `push` action creator inside your saga to navigate to a new location:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

 //... your saga code
 // api return success
 yield put(SUBMIT_ORDER_SUCCESS); // your existing action
 yield put(push('/orders/:orderId/complete')); //  use push to redirect to desired location
```

Comment: i wasn't sure if it was appropriate to do routing from within a saga, but with more reading and using react-router-redux, i see the router as just another piece of application state.  i'll also add an optional `redirect` prop to the action i pass to the saga, and use that in the `put(push())`