# chain redux actions without using callback

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

When I want to chain Redux actions, I use callbacks, but I want a clean solution without using callbacks. I don't want to use this methodology:

```js
export const onClick = () => fetchRequest1(id, fetchRequest2)
export const fetchRequest1 = (id, callback) => {
  ...
  // on success
  call(fetchRequest2 , data)
}
```

Comment: Where is your redux-saga code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to achieve callbacks in Redux-Saga?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076600/how-to-achieve-callbacks-in-redux-saga)

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this case by using async await syntax

```
export const brand_fetchAll = () => {
return async dispatch => {

try{
  const res=await  fetch(apiURL+'brand')
  const data= await res.json()
    dispatch({ type: 'BRAND_STORE_ALL',content})
    }  catch (error) {
    alert(error.message)
    }
}}
```

Comment: in my case bro , i'm using saga , so i dispatch the request using an action

Answer (score 0):

You can use Actions Creator to create callback-capability standardized actions

```sh
npm install actions-creator
```

```js
import actionsCreator from "actions-creator"
const my_callback = () => {
    console.log("Hello, I am callback!!!")
}
const callbackable_action = actionsCreator.CALLBACKABLE.EXAMPLE(1, 2, 3, my_callback)
console.log(callbackable_action)
//      {
//          type: "CALLBACKABLE/EXAMPLE",
//          args: [1, 2, 3],
//          cb: f() my_callback,
//          _index: 1
//      }
callbackable_action.cb()
//      "Hello, I am callback!!!"
```

see: [Actions Creator](https://github.com/Ruben-Arushanyan/actions-creator)